# Can I edit a WebP animation file to remove the auto loop?

Tags: animation, webp

I have a webp animation all setup but it is auto looping when it should top on the last frame (6s, 25fps). The tools I have used to create the webp do not let me configure the loop. Is there a way for me to edit the current webp file to remove the looping without using another animation tool?